# finding matched pairs(or records) in a dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a huge dataset from where I need to matched samples based on some criteria. For example, for every movie star in a location and borough find me two people (random) who are not movie stars. It is 1 for movie star and 0 for non-movie star.

```
 location<- c('manhattan', 'manhattan' ,'manhattan', 'manhattan', 'manhattan', 'manhattan')
 moviestar<- c(0,1,0,0,0,1)
 id<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
 borough <- c('williamsburg', 'williamsburg', 'williamsburg', 'williamsburg', 'williamsburg','williamsburg')

  df<- data.frame(location,moviestar, borough)
```

I want to create a subset which has matched pairs of movie star with two other non-movie stars (randomly picked) living in the same location and borough. Any advise?Essentially there are 6 people living in manhattan and there are two stars living in manhattan and I want to match for each star, in this case, 2 and 6 are stars, then I would like to have matched pairs in the final data as follows:

The output I am expecting is like this,

```
  > subset 
  location moviestar borough       id matchpairid
  manhattan    1    williamsburg   2  match1
  manhattan    0    williamsburg   1  match1
  manhttan     0    williamsburg   5  match1
  manhattan    1    williamsburg   6  match2
  manhattan    0    williamsburg   3  match2
  manhttan     0    williamsburg   5  match2
```

Comment: If there aren't two non-movie stars for each movie star, you mean you should drop the row? (Like you did for the `paris` one?)

Comment: yes that's right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In data.table, you could do this with the following

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[df[, keeper := max(moviestar) == 1, by=.(location, borough)][(keeper),
            if(any(moviestar == 0)) c(sample(.I[moviestar == 0], 2 * sum(moviestar)),
                                             .I[moviestar == 1]), by=.(location, borough)]$V1
          ][, keeper := NULL][]

    location moviestar      borough
1: manhattan         0 williamsburg
2: manhattan         0 williamsburg
3: manhattan         1 williamsburg
```

keeper is assigned TRUE in the boroughs with moviestars. Then it is used to subset the data. In the second j statement, check if there are any non-moviestars. If yes, sample 2 rows of non-moviestars (using `.I`) for every moviestar in the borough, also include movie stars. `$V1` extracts these indices. feed this to the original dataset to pull in the results.

`keeper := NULL` removes the intermediate keeper variable and `[]` at the end prints the result.

Comment: can i use 'location' as well in the by command in the keep function instead of just borough?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a unique name like match1, match2 etc., so I will know which are the matched pairs in the sample? An additional column so i know which one is matched to which. For example, if I have multiple stars says id- 10, 40 etc, when I run the code I get matched pairs for 10 as 23, 34 and for 40 as 12, 36, when I run these as whole I know there are matched pairs and not which one is matched to which. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is usually a good idea to post a new question rather than edit an old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by counting the number of movie stars and non-movie stars per group, then filtering within each group based on that condition:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  mutate(num_movie_stars = sum(moviestar),
         num_non_movie_stars = sum(1 - moviestar)) %>%
  group_by(location, moviestar) %>%
  filter(moviestar & row_number() <= num_non_movie_stars / 2 |
         !moviestar & row_number() <= num_movie_stars * 2) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Great! Does the filter command here select random records of non-movie stars?

Comment: @user3570187 rather than random it's the first X of each. But if you added a `sample_frac(1) %>%`  line at the start to shuffle the rows, it would become random.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a unique name like match1, match2 etc., so I will know which are the matched pairs in the sample?

Answer (score 0):

And a simple no package answer:

```
starstruck <- function(location, borough, df){
  subsamp <- df[which(location == df$location & borough == df$borough),]
  stars <- subsamp[subsamp$moviestar == 1,]
  nostars <- subsamp[subsamp$moviestar == 0,]
  randomcombo <- rbind(stars[sample(nrow(stars), 1, F),], 
                       nostars[sample(nrow(nostars), 2, F),])
  randomcombo[order(rownames(randomcombo)),]
}

starstruck("manhattan", "williamsburg", df)
#   location moviestar      borough
#1 manhattan         0 williamsburg
#2 manhattan         1 williamsburg
#3 manhattan         0 williamsburg
```

Comment: Updated to reflect random sampling, for non data.table or dplyr R users.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a unique name like match1, match2 etc., so I will know which are the matched pairs in the sample? An additional column so i know which one is matched to which.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you are referring to. This is pulling 2 no stars, and 1 star, at random, for the location and borough you indicate. Perhaps if you simply add an id column to your original dataset and then run the function it will show you what you want? `df2 <- cbind(df, id = 1:nrow(df)) ; starstruck("manhattan", "williamsburg", df2)`

Comment: Got it, thanks so much! What I meant is, if I have multiple stars says id- 10, 40 etc, when I run the code I get matched pairs for 10 as 23, 34 and for 40 as 12, 36, when I run these as whole I know there are matched pairs and not which one is matched to which. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you mind editing your post to show those results so I can better understand it? I'm not sure where stars are matched to not stars in your example data. I only see stars and not stars in a given location/borough.

Comment: I have made the changes, let me know if you can understand my question better. thanks so much